# Rewrite unicode characters in file to escaped ascii decimal representation in bash

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8

I am doing preprocessing on source code before compiling it. I need to convert any non-ascii characters into escaped decimal equivalents. For instance this:

```
fun main () = print "한"; ()
```

Must be converted into this:

```
fun main () = print "\237\149\156"
```

This should be pretty simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Some similar problems suggested using `iconv` but that seemed to be for encoding already escaped strings.

To reiterate, I am trying to preprocess some source code using bash commands to convert all non-ascii (utf-8 encoded) characters into their escaped decimal equivalent. Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using Perl:

```
perl -wpe 's/([^\x00-\x7F])/sprintf "\\%03d", ord $1/eg' < input > output
```

Explanation of some of the less-obvious bits:

- The `/e` flag says to treat the replacement-string — in this case `sprintf "\\%03d", ord $1` — as Perl code, and use its result.
- `ord` takes a character (in this case a single byte) and returns its numeric value.
- `sprintf` takes a format-string and a series of values, and return a string consisting of the format-string with the values appropriately substituted. `%03d` means "a decimal integer, zero-padded to three digits".

Comment: This is really great. Thank you very much for the explanation as well.